# What terminal to use with a tiling window manager?

Tags: linux, window-manager

I am using `i3` tiling window manager.

What would you suggest to use as a terminal with this tiling window manager?

I thought about `tilda` but they may be even better.

Comment: I wouldnt make up your mind until youve tried Terminator. You have configurations, which is taking an i3 workspace, presetting all of your window heights and widths, and saving that configuration. Do a google image search of "terminator terminal preferences". Oh yea, and the terminals' boundaries are movable via mouse (unlike tmux.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any requirements?

I use `urxvt` and find it the best terminal emulator when it comes to lightweight and performance. The most commonly mentioned pros are:

- Low memory usage
- High performance
- Unicode support
- Minimum dependencies and simple text config
- Fast text rendering
- Supports transparency

I personally like how it looks when multiple windows are tiled together, as it has no window decorations whatsoever, and how it saves configuration in a simple text file (so does `i3wm` so you can have a bunch of config files for various tools that you just drop into a newly created user account and get an environment you're used to in seconds).

Answer (score 2):

- [**terminator**](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html) is a little project to produce an efficient way of filling a large area of screen space with terminals. Terminator supports tabs and multiple resizable terminal panes in one window. The user can have multiple terminals arranged like tiles in one window and use key bindings to switch between them.
- **gnome-terminal** features the ability to use multiple terminals in a single window (tabs) and profiles support.

To change your terminal emulator, open your i3 configuration file and look for the commented section about starting a terminal (`# start a terminal`). You should see something like this in the file.

```
bindsym $mod+Return exec i3-sensible-terminal
```

To use i3 with a different emulator replace `i3-sensible-terminal` in the above line with the name of the new terminal emulator.